# python check if a method is called without mocking it away

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, magicmock

```
class A():
    def tmp(self):
        print("hi")

def b(a):
    a.tmp()
```

To check if tmp method is called in b, the recommended way is

```
a = A()
a.tmp = MagicMock()
b(a)
a.tmp.assert_called()
```

But tmp here is being mocked away and is not resulting in a `"hi"` getting printed.

I would want my unit test to check if method tmp is called without mocking it away.

Is this possible?

I know this is not a standard thing to expect when writing unitests. But my use case (which is bit tricky) requires this.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can set the [`Mock.side_effect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect) to be the original method.

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

class A():
    def tmp(self):
        print("hi")

def b(a):
    a.tmp()

a = A()
a.tmp = MagicMock(side_effect=a.tmp)
b(a)
a.tmp.assert_called()
```

When `side_effect` is a function (or a bound method in this case, which is a kind of function), calling the `Mock` will also call the `side_effect` with the same arguments.

The `Mock()` call will return whatever the `side_effect` returns, unless it returns the [`unnittest.mock.DEFAULT`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.DEFAULT) singleton. Then it will return [`Mock.return_value`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.return_value) instead.

Comment: def tmp(self):
        return "hi"

Comment: what if I care about return value as well?

Comment: @claudius Did you try it?  Calling the `Mock` object should return whatever `side_effect` returns with those arguments.

Comment: import should be from mock import MagicMock :)

Comment: What if you don't have access to the A object instance?

Comment: @cowlinator It depends on how everything is set up, you should probably ask a new question so you can include all the relevant details.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @Patrick Haugh's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50970170/python-check-if-a-method-is-called-without-mocking-it-away/50970342#50970342), you can also pass the function to the [`wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#the-mock-class) argument (and it seems more semantically correct to me).

> wraps: Item for the mock object to wrap. If wraps is not None then calling the Mock will pass the call through to the wrapped object (returning the real result). Attribute access on the mock will return a Mock object that wraps the corresponding attribute of the wrapped object (so attempting to access an attribute that doesn’t exist will raise an AttributeError).

```py
a = A()
a.tmp = MagicMock(wraps=a.tmp)
b(a)
a.tmp.assert_called()
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can decorate the method to test:

```
def check_called(fun):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kw):
        attrname = "_{}_called".format(fun.__name__)
        setattr(self, attrname, True)
        return fun(self, *args, **kw)
    return wrapper


a = A()
a.tmp = check_called(a.tmp)
b(a)
assert(getattr(a, "_tmp_called", False))
```

but MagicMock's `side_effect` is definitly a better solution if you're already using Mock ;)